# Color/Opacity Loss when converting XLSX to PDF using Acrobat IX

Tags: microsoft-excel, adobe-acrobat

It's all in the title. I've got an excel file I need converted to PDF for printing, and exporting it using either the Save As... function or the 'Create PDF' option in the Acrobat Ribbon both result in loss of opacity and color for cell borders and fill. I've looked all over every option I can find for converting to PDF (color options for Create PDF are set to 'Preserve', etc.) but still no dice-- I get black and white and no fill for my cells. What am I doing wrong?